# Opening file from Finder doesnt take me to the default Application

Tags: macos, finder, imac

When I try to open a file from Finder, either by double-clicking on the icon or choosing Right-click->open, I am not taken to the default application which is default for that file.

I need to go to the Application manually before I see that opened file.

I didnt face this problem earlier, which suddenly have come to bugging me recently.

Is there any way to correct it, so that I will be move to the default application automatically after I click an icon in the Finder?

Any pointer will be highly appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What version of MacOS? Is this all files, or specific file types?

Comment: Normally, when you double-click on a file, the application launches, comes to the front, and loads the document as a window. Is this not happening, or are you expecting some other behaviour?

Comment: You mean the file opens in the correct app, but that app is not brought to the front? If so, do you have windows open for that app on more than one Space?

Comment: @Tetsujin - yes, that is correct, The App is not coming to front, and I manually need to bring it to the front. In some cases, I have the windows open for that App, but in other cases I need to open the App new based on the click on the icon.

Comment: Does it work correctly just after a reboot if you set apps to not resume, or does it always fail?

Comment: @benwiggy - The part "comes to the front," is not happening. Is there any solution for that? I am facing this problem only recently, not sure if I changed any setting unintentionally. Appreciate for any solution for that

Comment: @Tetsujin - it is failing always

Comment: All apps, or just specific? If it's specific, I'd be tempted to ask the maker, see if it's something they've heard of.

Comment: So it just stays focused on the Finder, but the document window displays in the background? That's very strange.

Comment: Yes indeed  a bit strange

Comment: two more tests - Test a different account. Test on a safe boot.